# Parse a config file (.ini or .cfg) with CMake to create a header file

Tags: c++, cmake

In the CMake tutorial https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html#adding-a-version-number-and-configured-header-file, we can set several variables and then generate a header file using a template file (*.in).
For example:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6)
project (Tutorial)
set (MY_VAR_1 1)
set (MY_VAR_2 2)
set (MY_VAR_3 3)

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tutorial.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tutorial.h"
  )
```

```
// tutorial.h.in
#define MY_VARS_1 @MY_VARS_1@
#define MY_VARS_2 @MY_VARS_2@
#define MY_VARS_3 @MY_VARS_3@
```

Running `mkdir build && cmake ..` will generate tutorial.h with the declared variables. So far so good.

If I have a lot of variables for my application, and I would like to define the parameters in a .ini or .cfg file instead of in CMakeLists.txt. How can I parse the configuration file with CMake?

Comment: Nothing is built into cmake to do this.  You'll need to use some external tool to generate the file and invoke said tool via cmake.  Look into `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target`.

Comment: Also, I would look askance at the overall approach. Having lots of variables that change how / what is being compiled, and "hiding" them in the build process, is an invitation for headaches down the road...

Comment: @DevSolar, thanks, and yes, you are right. But this variables shall be fix for a repository of a project variant. What would be your better suggestion to deal with different variants of software that has similar code base?

Comment: You can make the variables in their own file included from your CMakeLists.txt and possibly put this file in a separate folder perhaps named Settings

Comment: @drescherjm, so you meant creating a new CMakeLists.txt in a new folder e.g. `config` that contains only the variables 
`set (MY_VAR_1 1) ... set (MY_VAR_X X)` and include it with add_directory(config)?

Comment: That was my general idea.

Comment: thanks @drescherjm, I thought about that too, but not sure if it is a best practice in 2021.

Comment: I usually will make these CMake OPTIONS with default values and let the user change. [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html)

Comment: Thanks for the OPTIONS tips. However, the context is more about software variants, rather than build options, which shall be documented as a file too. Furthermore, if something happens in the production app, the analysis of the variables should be clear and not hidden during the build execution.

Comment: Thanks @StephenNewell for the hint to the `add_custom_command`. However, it needs an external tool. Which external tool would you recommend?

Comment: @ywiyogo - What tools are good depends a lot on the environment where you'll be invoking cmake, so I couldn't give a recommendation without knowing those details.  Tool recommendations are also usually considered off topic, so you're better off using your favorite search engine.

Comment: I would recommend using cmake script file for these variables, if you really don't want to go with cache variables in the main file, bit I DO NOT recomment including this file via `add_subdirectory`; instead use `include(MySettings.cmake)`; However&documenting the possible options via `OPTIONS`/`CACHE` varibles is preferrable; you can still convenient pass a set of values during configuration using the `-C` command line option; how you use these values is up to you; generating a header or some other kind of file is possible of course.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 1) what you mean by "software variants" and 2) how they are different than build options- and put that elaboration in your question description? It seems like it's an important detail, given that the suggestions people are giving you don't seem preferable to you. I personally can't tell why without more explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CMake 3.19 came the feature of parsing JSON from strings with the [`string`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#json) command.

So let's say your configuration file is "config.json" in the same directory as the "CMakeLists.txt" file, containing something like this:

```json
{
  "project": {
    "version": "3.2.1",
    "dependencies": {
      "boost": "1.77",
      "openssl": "1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

You can do this to parse it:

```
file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/config.json" config_json)

string(JSON project_version GET "${config_json}"
       project version)
string(JSON boost_version GET "${config_json}"
       project dependencies boost)
string(JSON openssl_version GET "${config_json}"
       project dependencies openssl)

message(STATUS "Project version is ${project_version}")
message(STATUS "Boost version is ${boost_version}")
message(STATUS "OpenSSL version is ${openssl_version}")
```

Output:

```
-- Project version is 3.2.1
-- Boost version is 1.77
-- OpenSSL version is 1.1
```